# Container keeps crashing for Pod in minikube after the creation of PV and PVC

Tags: containers, minikube, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

i have a REST application integrated with kubernetes for testing REST queries. Now when i execute a POST query on my client side the status of the job which is automatically created remains `PENDING` indefinitely. The same happens with the POD which is also created automatically

When i looked deeper into the events in dashboard, it attaches the volume but is unable to mount the volume and gives this error :

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "ingestion-88dhg_default(4a8dd589-e3d3-4424-bc11-27d51822d85b)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"ingestion-88dhg". list of unmounted volumes=[cdiworkspace-volume]. list of unattached volumes=[cdiworkspace-volume default-token-qz2nb]
```

i have defined the persistent volume and persistent volume claim manually using following codes but did not connect to any pods. Should i do that?

**PV**

```
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "cdiworkspace",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/persistentvolumes/cdiworkspace",
    "uid": "92252f76-fe51-4225-9b63-4d6228d9e5ea",
    "resourceVersion": "100026",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-10T09:49:04Z",
    "annotations": {
      "pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller": "yes"
    },
    "finalizers": [
      "kubernetes.io/pv-protection"
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "10Gi"
    },
    "fc": {
      "targetWWNs": [
        "50060e801049cfd1"
      ],
      "lun": 0
    },
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "claimRef": {
      "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
      "namespace": "default",
      "name": "cdiworkspace",
      "uid": "0ce96c77-9e0d-4b1f-88bb-ad8b84072000",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "resourceVersion": "98688"
    },
    "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Retain",
    "storageClassName": "standard",
    "volumeMode": "Block"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Bound"
  }
}
```

**PVC**

```
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "cdiworkspace",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/cdiworkspace",
    "uid": "0ce96c77-9e0d-4b1f-88bb-ad8b84072000",
    "resourceVersion": "100028",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-07-10T09:32:16Z",
    "annotations": {
      "pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed": "yes",
      "pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller": "yes",
      "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner": "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath"
    },
    "finalizers": [
      "kubernetes.io/pvc-protection"
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "10Gi"
      }
    },
    "volumeName": "cdiworkspace",
    "storageClassName": "standard",
    "volumeMode": "Block"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Bound",
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "10Gi"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result of `journalctl -xe _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service`**

```
Jul 01 09:47:26 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:47:26.979098   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:47:40 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:47:40.979722   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:47:55 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:47:55.978806   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:48:08 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:48:08.979375   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:48:23 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:48:23.979463   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:48:37 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:48:37.979005   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:48:48 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:48:48.977686   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:49:02 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:49:02.979125   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:49:17 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:49:17.979408   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:49:28 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:49:28.977499   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:49:41 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:49:41.977771   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:49:53 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:49:53.978605   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:50:05 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:50:05.980251   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:50:16 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:50:16.979292   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:50:31 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:50:31.978346   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:50:42 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:50:42.979302   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:50:55 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:50:55.978043   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:51:08 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:51:08.977540   22759 pod_workers.go:190] Error syncing pod 6577b694-f18d-4d7b-9a75-82dc17c908ca ("myplanet-d976447c6-dsfx9_default(6577b694-f18d-4d7
Jul 01 09:51:24 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:51:24.190929   22759 remote_image.go:113] PullImage "friendly/myplanet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" from image service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = E
Jul 01 09:51:24 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:51:24.190971   22759 kuberuntime_image.go:51] Pull image "friendly/myplanet:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response 
Jul 01 09:51:24 rehan-B85M-HD3 kubelet[22759]: E0701 09:51:24.191024   22759 kuberuntime_manager.go:775] container start failed: ErrImagePull: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon:
```

**Deployment Yaml**

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: back
        image: back:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: back
      volumes:
      - name: back
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /back
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch

COPY . /code

WORKDIR /code

CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "ingestion.py"]
```

**pyython file1**

```
import os
import shutil
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("ingestion")

import requests

import datahub

scihub_username = os.environ["scihub_username"]
scihub_password = os.environ["scihub_password"]
result_url = "http://" + os.environ["CDINRW_BASE_URL"] + "/jobs/" + os.environ["CDINRW_JOB_ID"] + "/results"

logger.info("Searching the Copernicus Open Access Hub")
scenes = datahub.search(username=scihub_username,
                        password=scihub_password,
                        producttype=os.getenv("producttype"),
                        platformname=os.getenv("platformname"),
                        days_back=os.getenv("days_back", 2),
                        footprint=os.getenv("footprint"),
                        max_cloud_cover_percentage=os.getenv("max_cloud_cover_percentage"),
                        start_date = os.getenv("start_date"),
                        end_date = os.getenv("end_date"))

logger.info("Found {} relevant scenes".format(len(scenes)))

job_results = []
for scene in scenes:
    # do not donwload a scene that has already been ingested
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join("/out_data", scene["title"]+".SAFE")):
        logger.info("The scene {} already exists in /out_data and will not be downloaded again.".format(scene["title"]))
        filename = scene["title"]+".SAFE"
    else:
        logger.info("Starting the download of scene {}".format(scene["title"]))
        filename = datahub.download(scene, "/tmp", scihub_username, scihub_password, unpack=True)
        logger.info("The download was successful.")
        shutil.move(filename, "/out_data")
    result_message = {"description": "test",
                      "type": "Raster",
                      "format": "SAFE",
                      "filename": os.path.basename(filename)}
    job_results.append(result_message)

res = requests.put(result_url, json=job_results, timeout=60)
res.raise_for_status()
```

**python file 2 **

```
import logging
import os
import urllib.parse
import zipfile

import requests

# constructing URLs for querying the data hub
_BASE_URL = "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/"
SITE = {}
SITE["SEARCH"] = _BASE_URL + "search?format=xml&sortedby=beginposition&order=desc&rows=100&start={offset}&q="
_PRODUCT_URL = _BASE_URL + "odata/v1/Products('{uuid}')/"
SITE["CHECKSUM"] = _PRODUCT_URL + "Checksum/Value/$value"
SITE["SAFEZIP"] = _PRODUCT_URL + "$value"

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _build_search_url(producttype=None, platformname=None, days_back=2, footprint=None, max_cloud_cover_percentage=None, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    search_terms = []
    if producttype:
        search_terms.append("producttype:{}".format(producttype))
    if platformname:
        search_terms.append("platformname:{}".format(platformname))
    if start_date and end_date:
        search_terms.append(
            "beginPosition:[{}+TO+{}]".format(start_date, end_date))
    elif days_back:
        search_terms.append(
            "beginPosition:[NOW-{}DAYS+TO+NOW]".format(days_back))
    if footprint:
        search_terms.append("footprint:%22Intersects({})%22".format(
            footprint.replace(" ", "+")))
    if max_cloud_cover_percentage:
        search_terms.append("cloudcoverpercentage:[0+TO+{}]".format(max_cloud_cover_percentage))
    url = SITE["SEARCH"] + "+AND+".join(search_terms)
    return url


def _unpack(zip_file, directory, remove_after=False):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as zf:
        # This assumes that the zipfile only contains the .SAFE directory at root level
        safe_path = zf.namelist()[0]
        zf.extractall(path=directory)
    if remove_after:
        os.remove(zip_file)
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(directory, safe_path))


def search(username, password, producttype=None, platformname=None ,days_back=2, footprint=None, max_cloud_cover_percentage=None, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    """ Search the Copernicus SciHub

    Parameters
    ----------
    username : str
      user name for the Copernicus SciHub
    password : str
      password for the Copernicus SciHub
    producttype : str, optional
      product type to filter for in the query (see https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/FullTextSearch#Search_Keywords for allowed values)
    platformname : str, optional 
      plattform name to filter for in the query (see https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/FullTextSearch#Search_Keywords for allowed values)
    days_back : int, optional
      number of days before today that will be searched. Default are the last 2 days. If start and end date are set the days_back parameter is ignored
    footprint : str, optional
      well-known-text representation of the footprint
    max_cloud_cover_percentage: str, optional
      percentage of cloud cover per scene. Can only be used in combination with Sentinel-2 imagery. 
      (see https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/FullTextSearch#Search_Keywords for allowed values)
    start_date: str, optional
        start point of the search extent has to be used in combination with end_date
    end_date: str, optional
        end_point of the search extent has to be used in combination with start_date

    Returns
    -------
    list
      a list of scenes that match the search parameters
    """

    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
    scenes = []
    search_url = _build_search_url(producttype, platformname, days_back, footprint, max_cloud_cover_percentage, start_date, end_date)
    logger.info("Search URL: {}".format(search_url))
    offset = 0
    rowsBreak = 5000
    name_space = {"atom": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
                  "opensearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"}
    while offset < rowsBreak:  # Next pagination page:
        response = requests.get(search_url.format(offset=offset), auth=(username, password))
        root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
        if offset == 0:
            rowsBreak = int(
                root.find("opensearch:totalResults", name_space).text)
        for e in root.iterfind("atom:entry", name_space):
            uuid = e.find("atom:id", name_space).text
            title = e.find("atom:title", name_space).text
            begin_position = e.find(
                "atom:date[@name='beginposition']", name_space).text
            end_position = e.find(
                "atom:date[@name='endposition']", name_space).text
            footprint = e.find("atom:str[@name='footprint']", name_space).text
            scenes.append({
                "id": uuid,
                "title": title,
                "begin_position": begin_position,
                "end_position": end_position,
                "footprint": footprint})
        # Ultimate DHuS pagination page size limit (rows per page).
        offset += 100
    return scenes


def download(scene, directory, username, password, unpack=True):
    """ Download a Sentinel scene based on its uuid

    Parameters
    ----------
    scene : dict
        the scene to be downloaded
    path : str
        the path where the file will be downloaded to
    username : str
        username for the Copernicus SciHub
    password : str
        password for the Copernicus SciHub
    unpack: boolean, optional
        flag that defines whether the downloaded product should be unpacked after download. defaults to true

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        if the size of the downloaded file does not match the Content-Length header
    ValueError
        if the checksum of the downloaded file does not match the checksum provided by the Copernicus SciHub

    Returns
    -------
    str
        path to the downloaded file
    """

    import hashlib
    md5hash = hashlib.md5()
    md5sum = requests.get(SITE["CHECKSUM"].format(
        uuid=scene["id"]), auth=(username, password)).text

    download_path = os.path.join(directory, scene["title"] + ".zip")
    # overwrite if path already exists
    if os.path.exists(download_path):
        os.remove(download_path)
    url = SITE["SAFEZIP"].format(uuid=scene["id"])
    rsp = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), stream=True)
    cl = rsp.headers.get("Content-Length")
    size = int(cl) if cl else -1
    # Actually fetch now:
    with open(download_path, "wb") as f:  # Do not read as a whole into memory:
        written = 0
        for block in rsp.iter_content(8192):
            f.write(block)
            written += len(block)
            md5hash.update(block)
    written = os.path.getsize(download_path)
    if size > -1 and written != size:
        raise ValueError("{}: size mismatch, {} bytes written but expected {} bytes to write!".format(
            download_path, written, size))
    elif md5sum:
        calculated = md5hash.hexdigest()
        expected = md5sum.lower()
        if calculated != expected:
            raise ValueError("{}: MD5 mismatch, calculated {} but expected {}!".format(
                download_path, calculated, expected))
    if unpack:
        return _unpack(download_path, directory, remove_after=False)
    else:
        return download_path
```

How can i mount the volume properly and automatically onto the pod? **i do not want to create the pods manually for each REST service and assign volumes to them**

Comment: A few additional questions: Could you check and post the result of `journalctl -xe _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service` ? Is there anything related to problems with mounting volumes ? Another thing... Could you also show your `Deployment`/`Pod` definition where your mount of the volume is declared ?

Comment: @mario i have added the response from above statement to question. However, The image that it shows in the error is not from minikube docker. it's from my system's docker but interesting thing is that i have an already running deployment from an image on minikube docker which runs fine. is it not setting the docker environment correctly?

Comment: @mario also i have added the Deployment.yaml file for broken pod if that's what you meant by pod definition however i am not mounting the volume anywhere explicitly?

Comment: as to the logs, I cannot see there anything related to problems with mounting volumes, so ignore them for now, please check the steps described in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i went through the logs of the pod again and realized that the parameters required by **python file1** were not being provided and were causing the container to crash. i tested it by providing all the missing parameters pointed out in logs and giving them in `deployment.yaml` for the pod which looked like this now:

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: back
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 
      labels:
        app: back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: back
        image: back:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: scihub_username
          value: test
        - name: scihub_password
          value: test
        - name: CDINRW_BASE_URL
          value: 10.1.40.11:8081/swagger-ui.html
        - name: CDINRW_JOB_ID
          value: 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: test-volume
      volumes:
      - name: test-volume
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /back
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
```

This started downloading the data and solved the problem for now however this is not how i want it to run as i want it to be triggered through a REST API which provides all parameters and starts and stops this container. i'll create a separate question for that and link it below for anyone to follow.

Answer (score 0):

> i have defined the persistent volume and persistent volume claim
>   manually using following codes but did not connect to any pods. Should
>   i do that?

So you didn't refer to it in any way then in your `Pod` definition till now, right ? At least I cannot see it anywhere in your `Deployment`. If so, the answer is: yes, you must do that so that Pods in your cluster can use it.

Let's start from the beginning. Basically the whole process of configuring a `Pod` (applies also to Pod template in Deployment definition) to use a `PersistentVolume` for storage consists of 3 steps [[source]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/):

> 1. A cluster administrator creates a `PersistentVolume` that is backed by physical storage. The administrator does not associate the volume
>      with any Pod.
> 2. A cluster user creates a `PersistentVolumeClaim`, which gets automatically bound to a suitable `PersistentVolume`.
> 3. The user creates a `Pod` ( it can be also a `Deployment` in which you define a certain Pod template specification ) that uses the `PersistentVolumeClaim` as storage.

It makes no sense to describe here in detail all above mentioned steps as it was already done very well [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

You can verify the PV/PVC availability using the following commands:

`kubectl get pv volume-name` on this stage should show the status of your volume as `Bound`

the same with `kubectl get pvc task-pv-claim` ( in your case `kubectl get pvc cdiworkspace` however I would recommend to use different name e.g. cdiworkspace-claim for `PersistentVolumeClaim` so it can be easily differentiated from `PersistentVolume` itself) - this command also should show the status of `Bound`

Please notice that the Pod’s configuration file specifies only `PersistentVolumeClaim`, but it does not specify a `PersistentVolume` itself. From the Pod’s point of view, the claim is a volume. Here is a nice description which clearly marks the difference between those two objects [[source]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#introduction):

> A PersistentVolume (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has
>   been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using
>   Storage Classes. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a
>   cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a
>   lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV. This API
>   object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be
>   that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.
>
> A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It
>   is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV
>   resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and
>   Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can
>   be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).

Below example of specification in `Pod` / `Deployment` definition which refers to existing `PersistentVolumeClaim`:

```
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

As to your question:

> How can i mount the volume properly and automatically onto the pod? i
>   do not want to create the pods manually for each REST service and
>   assign volumes to them

You don't have to create them manually. You may specify the `PersistentVolumeClaim` they use in Pod template specification in your `Deployment` definition.

**Docummentation resources:**

Detailed step by step description of how to configure a Pod to use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` for storage you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

More about the concept of Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes can be found in this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

If you want to share some data available on your **minikube** host with every **Pod** in your cluster, there is much simpler approach than `PersistentVolume`. It is called `hostPath`. Detailed description you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), and below an example that may be useful in your particular case:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: test-volume
      volumes:
      - name: test-volume
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /directory/with/python/files
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
```

Examples that you posted are actually in `json`, not in `yaml` format. You should be able to convert them easily to required format on [this](https://www.json2yaml.com/) page. You should place your files in `/directory/with/python/files` on your **minikube** host and they will be available in /data directory in each Pod created by your deployment.

Below your deployment in yaml format with `/directory/with/python/files` directory on your host mounted at /data using **hostPath**:

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: back
  namespace: default
  selfLink: "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/back"
  uid: 9f21717c-2c04-459f-b47a-95fd8e11728d
  resourceVersion: '298987'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2019-07-16T13:16:15Z'
  labels:
    run: back
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: back
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 
      labels:
        run: back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: back
        image: back:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: test-volume
      volumes:
      - name: test-volume
        hostPath:
          # directory location on host
          path: /directory/with/python/files
          # this field is optional
          type: Directory
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: "/dev/termination-log"
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - type: Progressing
    status: 'True'
    lastUpdateTime: '2019-07-16T13:16:34Z'
    lastTransitionTime: '2019-07-16T13:16:15Z'
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    message: ReplicaSet "back-7fd9995747" has successfully progressed.
  - type: Available
    status: 'False'
    lastUpdateTime: '2019-07-19T08:32:49Z'
    lastTransitionTime: '2019-07-19T08:32:49Z'
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
```

Comment: do i need to define the secrets as well because currently in my pod under `volumeMounts` when i create pod using the above answer, it's using the default secrets and which volume is the `task-pv-storage` in the pod creation example. could you please define that. it's not defined anywhere

Comment: also i don't think it's to do with PV/PVC configurations because one of my containers  without any python files is running fine but the rest which require the docker file to run an python file are putting up error `back-off restarting failed container`. i have attached a docker file and it's supporting file for further look

Comment: If your Pods use some specific secret, you should refer it in Deployment definition. You can read more about using secrets https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets  As to other error, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with previous one you mentioned. And how do you provide those files to pods ? Are they available through the mounted volume ?

Comment: so i mount my local repository where the files are stored then i ssh into minikube and build the docker image in minikube and then exit out. then i am deploying and creating pod through this : `sudo kubectl run back --image=back:latest --port=8080 --image-pull-policy Never `. When i build the image in minikube,i guess they should have all those files. how should i give the mount path for the volume created in minikube?

Comment: Anything interesting in container logs ? Try `docker logs container-name` or `kubectl logs pod-name` So it doesn't use `PersistentVolumeClaim` but some host folder ? Take a look also at this https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#persistent-volumes

Comment: for both commands the output is `no such container:back` &`pods:back not found`. Although both the image and pod are available within minikube

Comment: how should i define the ` mount path` in `volume mount` when creating the pod in above answer. The xample in docs runs fine. i created a `/mnt/data` directory and built my image inside it but it resulted in the same error. What's the proper way to declare path and what should be there?

Comment: @rehan, please see my last edit to my answer, I guess this may be actually better solution for you than using `PersistentVolume`, especially if you use simple one-node minikube installation.